# Getting content-length but no content

Tags: jquery, json, http, lua, cgi

I'm sending a POST request with data, but I don't receive any data.

Calling the request:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"ajaxtest.lp",
    dataType:'json',
    contentType:'json',
    data:"{name:'lolbert',surname:'roflcopter'}"
})
```

What's going out:

**HEADER:**

```
Connection  
close
Content-Type    
text/html
Date    
Thu, 01 Jan 1970 07:24:40 GMT
Server  
Core4Web
Quelltext anzeigen
Accept  
application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding 
gzip, deflate
Accept-Language 
de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Content-Length  
31
Content-Type    
json; charset=UTF-8
Host    
192.168.207.117
Referer 
http://192.168.207.117/ajaxtest.lp
User-Agent  
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0
X-Requested-With    
XMLHttpRequest
```

**POST (via Firebug):**

```
name=lolbert&surname=roflcopter
```

But what I'm receiving on the server side is somehow strange.
The content-length is correct (37 chars) but the content itself is missing.

> **** request
>   script_file request script_file     ajaxtest.lp
>   client_content_type request client_content_type     json; charset=UTF-8
>   client_port request client_port     64626
>   method request method  post
>   client_address request client_address  192.168.203.59
>   client_content_length request client_content_length   37
>   urn request urn     /ajaxtest.lp
>   script_vpath request script_vpath    /ajaxtest.lp
>   script_path request script_path     /usr/lib/htdocs/ajaxtest.lp
>   script_pdir request script_pdir     /usr/lib/htdocs/
>   script_vdir request script_vdir     /
>    **** header
>   Content-Type header  Content-Type    json; charset=UTF-8
>   Accept-Encoding header  Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
>   X-Requested-With header  X-Requested-With        XMLHttpRequest
>   Accept-Language header  Accept-Language de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
>   Connection header  Connection      keep-alive
>   Pragma header  Pragma  no-cache
>   **Content-Length header  Content-Length  37**
>   Host header  Host    192.168.207.117
>   User-Agent header  User-Agent      Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0
>   Accept header  Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
>   Referer header  Referer http://192.168.207.117/ajaxtest.lp
>   Cache-Control header  Cache-Control   no-cache
>   **** file
>   script_path file    script_path     /usr/lib/htdocs/ajaxtest.lua
>   script_pdir file    script_pdir     /usr/lib/htdocs/
>   urn file    urn     ajaxtest.lua
>   script_vpath file    script_vpath    /ajaxtest.lua
>   nesting_level file    nesting_level   1
>   script_file file    script_file     ajaxtest.lua
>   script_vdir file    script_vdir     /

Comment: You should pass object as data to `$.post` method, not string: `data:{"name":"lolbert","surname":"roflcopter"}`. And set it as valid JSON notation, because you are setting `contentType:'json',` (even not sure how jQuery would handle it?!)

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"ajaxtest.lp",
    dataType:'json',
    contentType:'json',
    data:{name:'lolbert',surname:'roflcopter'}
});
```

Please try to send data with object.

Comment: Everything keeps exactly the same, except the content-length is shorter.

Comment: try to remove dataType and contentType objects from ajax object, so it looks like this

$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"ajaxtest.lp",
    data:{name:'lolbert',surname:'roflcopter'}
});

if that does not work - then there is a problem with link. Please tell me results

Answer (score 0):

Is not a correct JSON data: http://www.json.org/ try with:

```
data: '{"name": "lolbert","surname": "roflcopter"}'
```

You can check the correct JSON format with online tools (like http://jsonlint.com/ for example).

Comment: Content-length is 31 instead of 37 now, Firebug identifies the outgoing data as json now, problem of lack of data remains.

Comment: If now Firebug identifies the outgoing data as json perhaps the problem was on server side... what's the content of ajax test.lp?

By the way, is a good idea to create an object with the data that you want to send.

Take a look to this url, perhaps can help: http://www.irayfuego.es/una-sencilla-llamada-ajax-con-jquery/